# inheritance issue “cannot find symbol: method” but the method is declared

Tags: java, inheritance

When i try to compile my Java program with the following code:

This is within my ticketorder.java file

```
   class TicketOrder extends FreeSeat {
```

---

```
StudentTicket StudentObject = new StudentTicket();     // Created a class and class constructor named StudentTicket
            StudentObject.DiscountStudentBought();                 // Notifies the customer has bought the ticket
            StudentObject.checkStatus();
            int Studentprice = StudentObject.getStudentPrice();    // Takes the price from the StudentTicket Class and assigns it to an integer
            Studentprice = Studentprice - 2;                       // Deducts a value of 2 from the price.
            TicketPrices.add(Studentprice);                        // Adds the final ticket price to an Array
```

This is within my FreeSeat.java file

```
class FreeSeat {

public void checkStatus() {

    System.out.println("Seat Booked");

}
```

}

When i try to compile the program it states

```
 error: cannot find symbol
  StudentObject.checkStatus();


Symbol:   method checkStatus()



location: variable StudedntObject of type StudentTicket


1 error
```

My question is, even though the checkStatus() is clearly inherited. Why is it stating this error message? Thanks.

Comment: `TicketOrder ` != `StudentTicket`?

Comment: Also, please, respect the Javanaming conventions. Variables start with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StudentTicket needs to extend FreeSeat not TicketOrder

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple error in your program. But I would like to solve the big hidden problem behind your question. Remember one thing whenever you start coding, first take pen and paper. Think about the flow and algorithms you are going to implement. And when you become confident then code.

Answer (score 1):

I guess Ticket order is your main class and you have inherited the FreeSeat class there &  you are trying to call the method of free seat class  via the object of StudentTicket class which has no such method inherited. To check just change StudentObject.checkStatus(); to  this.checkStatus(); you yourself will find where the issue is. and finally extend  FreeSeat to StudentTicket.